# ie6 float causes background image to dissapear

Tags: css-float, background-image, internet-explorer-6

I have a div with a background image which is aligned bottom right. Then I have another div floated inside that div to the left and to the bottom. In IE6, it looks like the bottom inner div is overlapping and cutting out the middle of the background image which is set to bottom left.

Any ideas what might cause this? Is there a known issue with floats and background images?

Thanks

Comment: Please post a full code example or a link to the site.

Comment: Have you considered not supporting IE6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the CSS property Zoom:1;  on the div with the background image. This sorts it out in IE6.